# Importing a function from another script

Tags: python, function

I experience `'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 16: invalid start byte` error while I was trying to import a function in the following way :

```
from Tutorials.Functions.Files import path_to_project_root
```

After some investigations, I found the problem was due to some additional calls on the *`path_to_project_root`* function in *`Tutorials.Functions.Files`* itself. In other words, my `Tutorials.Functions.Files` looks like this:

```
def path_to_project_root(projectName)
# The function body
return smt
path_to_project_root("myProject")
```

I realized that having a call to *`path_to_project_root("myProject")`* while I import it in another script is the problem, and just by commenting it out everything worked well. **I am seeking the rationale behind this issue.**

Answer (score 0):

This is how Python works, python is a script language, everything you want the interpreter know must be interpreted by interpreter first.

In this case, you import some function from `Files`, interpreter must read and execute it.

Just think what if you do some import in `path_to_project_root` function, without run all statements in the file, the module you import may not work fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but then what would be the difference between importing an entire script and importing just a function from the entire script like my case?

Comment: Actually no odds,  except you can use specific function you imported only cuz you  got the reference to the function you imported only.

Comment: The variable `sys.modules` include all module you imported, `import module` or `from module import function` impact the same to `sys.module`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but I still can not get your idea. Would you please simplify it more.

Comment: `Files` is a module, `path_to_project_root` is a function. When you `import Files` you got the reference to the module, otherwise, you got the reference to the function when `from X.X.Files import path_to_project_root`. That's all the difference.

Comment: The same point between these two operations is, they both execute the whole script in module, whatever you import module directly or just import a function from it.